# MySQL - Set user password with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, passwords, mysql-error-1064

I want to change an user's password using an stored procedure in MySQL.

Here is the creation code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA `try` ;
USE try;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`username`));

insert into users values('Admin','pass');

create user 'usertry'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';
grant select on try.* to 'usertry'@'localhost';
grant insert on try.* to 'usertry'@'localhost';
grant update on try.* to 'usertry'@'localhost';
grant delete on try.* to 'usertry'@'localhost';
```

Until here, everything is good.
Then i created a stored procedure to change the table "users".

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `changeusers` (
IN user VARCHAR(255),
IN pass VARCHAR(255),
IN newuser VARCHAR(255),
IN newpass VARCHAR(255),
OUT result bool)
BEGIN
if(user= Binary (Select username from users limit 1) 
and pass= Binary (Select password from users limit 1))
    then
        delete from users where username=user;
        insert into users values(newuser,newpass);
        set result=true;
    else
        set result=false;
end if;
select result;
END $$ DELIMITER ;
```

When i call the stored procedure, it works well.

```
call changeusers('Admin','pass','Admin','new',@result);

call changeusers('Admin','pass','Admin','new',@result)  1 row(s) returned   0.141 sec / 0.000 sec
```

Then i tried to change the stored procedure to set the user's password same as the password in the users table.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `changeusers` (
IN user VARCHAR(255),
IN pass VARCHAR(255),
IN newuser VARCHAR(255),
IN newpass VARCHAR(255),
OUT result bool)
BEGIN
if(user= Binary (Select username from users limit 1) 
and pass= Binary (Select password from users limit 1))
    then
        delete from users where username=user;
        insert into users values(newuser,newpass);

        /*The added line*/
        set password for 'usertry'@'localhost' = newpass;
        /*The added line*/

        set result=true;
    else
        set result=false;
end if;
select result;
END $$ DELIMITER ;
```

But when i run the new script i got this:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
    for the right syntax to use near 
       'newpass; 
            set result=true;         
        else             
            set result=false;' 
    at line 13  0.000 sec
```

I would apreciate any sugestions. 
Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Barmar. I was able to do what i want.
Here's the new stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `changeusers` (
IN user VARCHAR(255),
IN pass VARCHAR(255),
IN newuser VARCHAR(255),
IN newpass VARCHAR(255),
OUT result bool)
BEGIN
if(user= Binary (Select username from users limit 1) 
and pass= Binary (Select password from users limit 1))
    then
        delete from users where username=user;
        insert into users values(newuser,newpass);

        /*The added line*/
        set @stm = CONCAT("set password for 'usertry'@'localhost' = ",newpass);
        prepare stmt from @stm;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;
        /*The added line*/

        set result=true;
    else
        set result=false;
end if;
select result;
END $$ DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Try using the `ALTER USER` statement instead of `SET PASSWORD`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried using `ALTER USER`, but still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `SET PASSWORD` allows the password to be a variable, it has to be a literal (or a call to `PASSWORD()` with a literal parameter. So you need to use a prepared statement:

```
PREPARE @stmt FROM CONCAT("SET PASSWORD FOR 'usertry'@'localhost' = '", newpass, "'");
EXECUTE @stmt;
```